Playwright test failing: props return different values in Playwright testing UI and actual React app on Chrome browser
I am creating an e2e testing for my application using Playwright (version 1.44.1). I have a react 18 application (created with Vite) for a blogs app. When I run the application the UI shows correct props in the React components as well as console logs. However, when I run my Playwright tests in the Playwright GUI the props show different values and so the tests fail. I do not know how this is happening. Any help would be appreciated. Below are my files.
I have 3 folders

e2e (with Playwright)
blog-backend
blog-frontend

QUESTION: I do not understand why the props are different on the Chrome browser when run normally and the props are different in the Playwright tests. The props shape should have been the same. What am I doing wrong here?
My test file blog_app.spec.js in the e2e folder: Please note that I have written other tests and all others pass.
const { test, expect, beforeEach, describe } = require('@playwright/test');
const { loginWith, createBlog } = require('./helper');

describe('Blog app', () => {
  beforeEach(async ({ page, request }) => {
    // empty the database
    await request.post('http:localhost:3003/api/testing/reset');
    // create a user for the backend
    await request.post('http://localhost:3003/api/users', {
      data: {
        name: 'First Last',
        username: 'first',
        password: 'last'
      }
    });

    await page.goto('http://localhost:5173');
  });

  test('front page can be opened', async ({ page }) => { });
  test('Login form is shown', async ({ page }) => { });
  describe('Login', () => {
    test('succeeds with correct credentials', async ({ page }) => { });
    test('fails with wrong credentials', async ({ page }) => { });
  });

  describe('When logged in', () => {
    beforeEach(async ({ page }) => {
      await loginWith(page, 'first', 'last');
    });

    // THIS TEST DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED
    test('a new blog can be created', async ({ page }) => {
      await createBlog(page, 'first blog title', 'first blog author', 'first blog url');

      await expect(page.locator('li').filter({ hasText: 'first blog title' })).toBeVisible();

      await page.getByText('first blog title').locator('..').getByRole('button', { name: 'view' }).click();
      await expect(page.getByText('Author: first blog author')).toBeVisible();
      await expect(page.getByText('Likes: 0')).toBeVisible();
      await expect(page.getByText('URL: first blog url')).toBeVisible();
      await expect(page.getByText('Added by: ')).toBeVisible(); // THIS WORKS
      await expect(page.getByText('Added by: First Last')).toBeVisible(); // THIS DOES NOT WORK
      // await expect(page.getByRole('button', { name: 'remove' })).toBeVisible(); // THIS DOES NOT WORK
    });
  });
});

Below is the Playwright GUI output:

NOTE: the name, username, and logged in username are undefined in the Playwright GUI.
If you notice in the Playwright GUI console, the props received by the Blog.jsx file the object shape is how it is saved to the database in the backend:
{
  title: first blog title, 
  author: first blog author, 
  url: first blog url, 
  likes: 0, 
  user: 665fac3a37d34c2da6c8f899
}

Now running this application in a chrome browser receives different props shape:
Chrome browser view: Please notice the user that creates the blog name appears in the blog info. This shape is correct here.

The props shape in the Chrome browser is: In the frontend the below props show up correctly, and are also correctly reflected in the UI.
{
    "title": "first blog title",
    "author": "first blog author",
    "url": "first blog url",
    "likes": 0,
    "user": {
      "username": "first",
      "name": "First Last",
      "id": "665fac3a37d34c2da6c8f899"
    },
    "id": "665fac3b37d34c2da6c8f8a0"
}

See React Components props from the Chrome browser:

App.jsx file in the frontend:
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import Blog from './components/Blog';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm';
import NewBlogForm from './components/NewBlogForm';
import Notification from './components/Notification';
import Togglable from './components/Togglable';
import blogService from './services/blogs';
import loginService from './services/login';

const compareBlogs = (a, b) => {
  if (a.likes < b.likes) return 1;
  if (a.likes > b.likes) return -1;
  return 0;
};

const sortBlogsAsPerMostLikedFirst = (blogs) => {
  const sortedBlogs = blogs.sort(compareBlogs);
  return sortedBlogs;
};

const App = () => {
  const [blogs, setBlogs] = useState([]);
  const blogFormRef = useRef();
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState({
    message: '',
    isError: false,
  });
  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    blogService.getAll().then((initialBlogs) => {
      const sortedBlogs = sortBlogsAsPerMostLikedFirst(initialBlogs);
      setBlogs(sortedBlogs);
    });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedUserJSON = window.localStorage.getItem('loggedBlogappUser');
    if (loggedUserJSON) {
      const user = JSON.parse(loggedUserJSON);
      setUser(user);
      blogService.setToken(user.token);
    }
  }, []);

  const removeNotificationAfterFiveSeconds = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setNotification({
        message: '',
        isError: false,
      });
    }, 5000);
  };

  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const user = await loginService.login({
        username,
        password,
      });

      window.localStorage.setItem('loggedBlogappUser', JSON.stringify(user));

      blogService.setToken(user.token);
      setUser(user);
    } catch (error) {
      setNotification({
        message: error.response.data.error,
        isError: true,
      });
      removeNotificationAfterFiveSeconds();
    }
  };

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      window.localStorage.removeItem('loggedBlogappUser');
      setUser(null);
      setUsername('');
      setPassword('');
    } catch (exception) {
      console.error(exception.message);
    }
  };

  const addBlog = (blogObject) => {
    blogFormRef.current.toggleVisibility();

    blogService
      .create(blogObject)
      .then((returnedBlog) => {
        setBlogs(blogs.concat(returnedBlog));
        setNotification({
          message: `SUCCESS: Added ${returnedBlog.title} blog`,
          isError: false,
        });
        removeNotificationAfterFiveSeconds();
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setNotification({
          message: error.response.data.error,
          isError: true,
        });
        removeNotificationAfterFiveSeconds();
      });
  };

  const increaseLikes = (blogToUpdate) => {
    const blog = blogs.find((b) => b.id === blogToUpdate.id);
    const updatedBlog = { ...blog, likes: blog.likes + 1 };

    blogService
      .update(blog.id, updatedBlog)
      .then((returnedBlog) => {
        const blogList = blogs.map((blog) => blog.id !== blogToUpdate.id ? blog : returnedBlog);
        const sortedBlogs = sortBlogsAsPerMostLikedFirst(blogList);
        setBlogs(sortedBlogs);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        setNotification({
          message: `Blog '${blog.title}' was already removed from server`,
          isError: true,
        });
        removeNotificationAfterFiveSeconds();
        const blogList = blogs.filter((b) => b.id !== blogToUpdate.id);
        setBlogs(blogList);
        console.error(error.message);
      });
  };

  const deleteBlog = (blog) => {
    const toDelete = window.confirm(`Delete "${blog.title}" blog?`);
    console.log({ toDelete });

    if (toDelete) {
      blogService
        .deleteBlog(blog)
        .then(() => {
          const blogList = blogs.filter((b) => blog.id !== b.id);
          setBlogs(blogList);
          console.log('Blog deleted');
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err.message);
          alert('Sorry! Blog cannot be deleted as it is not created by you.');
        });
    }
  };

  const loginForm = () => {
    return (
      <Togglable buttonLabel="login">
        <LoginForm
          username={username}
          password={password}
          handleUsernameChange={({ target }) => setUsername(target.value)}
          handlePasswordChange={({ target }) => setPassword(target.value)}
          handleSubmit={handleLogin}
        />
      </Togglable>
    );
  };

  const blogForm = () => (
    <Togglable buttonLabel="new blog" ref={blogFormRef}>
      <NewBlogForm createBlog={addBlog} />
    </Togglable>
  );

  console.log('App.jsx', JSON.stringify(blogs)); // DEBUG

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Blogs</h1>

      <Notification notification={notification} />

      {!user && loginForm()}

      {user && (
        <div>
          <p>
            {user.name} logged in{' '}
            <button type="button" onClick={handleLogout}>
              logout
            </button>
          </p>

          {blogForm()}

          <ul style={{ listStyleType: 'none', padding: 0 }}>
            {blogs.map((blog) => (
              <Blog
                key={blog.id}
                blog={blog}
                loggedInUsername={user.username}
                handleLikes={() => increaseLikes(blog)}
                handleDeleteBlog={() => deleteBlog(blog)}
              />
            ))}
          </ul>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;

The Blog.jsx file in the frontend:
import { useState } from 'react';

const Blog = ({ blog, loggedInUsername, handleLikes, handleDeleteBlog }) => {
  console.log('Blog.jsx', blog); // DEBUG
  console.log('Blog creator username: ', blog.user.username); // DEBUG
  console.log('Blog creator name: ', blog.user.name); // DEBUG
  console.log('Logged in username: ', loggedInUsername, ); // DEBUG

  // styles
  const blogStyle = {
    paddingLeft: 10,
    paddingRight: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    border: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 1,
    marginBottom: 5,
  };
  const removeBtnStyle = {
    backgroundColor: 'lightblue',
    padding: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  };

  const [viewBlogInfo, setViewBlogInfo] = useState(false);

  const toggleShow = () => {
    setViewBlogInfo(!viewBlogInfo);
  };

  return (
    <li style={blogStyle} className='blog'>
      <p>
        <span>{blog.title}{' '}</span>
        <button onClick={toggleShow} className='viewHideBtn'>
          {viewBlogInfo ? 'hide' : 'view'}
        </button>
      </p>

      {viewBlogInfo && (
        <div>
          <div>
            <div>Author: {blog.author}</div>

            <div>
              <span data-testid='likes'>Likes: {blog.likes}</span>
              <button onClick={handleLikes} className='likeBtn'>like</button>
            </div>

            <div>URL: {blog.url}</div>

            <div>Added by: {blog.user.name}</div>
          </div>

          <br />

          {blog.user.username === loggedInUsername && (
            <div>
              <button style={removeBtnStyle} onClick={handleDeleteBlog} className='removeBtn'>
                remove
              </button>
            </div>
          )}
        </div>
      )}
    </li>
  );
};

export default Blog;

The blogs.js file for controllers in the backend:
const blogsRouter = require('express').Router();
const Blog = require('../models/blog');
const middleware = require('../utils/middleware');

blogsRouter.get('/', async (request, response) => {
  const blogs = await Blog.find({}).populate('user', { username: 1, name: 1 });
  response.json(blogs);
});

blogsRouter.get('/:id', async (request, response) => {
  const blog = await Blog.findById(request.params.id).populate('user', { username: 1, name: 1 });
  if (blog) {
    response.json(blog);
  } else {
    response.status(404).end();
  }
});

blogsRouter.post('/', middleware.userExtractor, async (request, response) => {
  const user = request.user;
  const body = request.body;

  const blog = new Blog({
    title: body.title,
    author: body.author,
    url: body.url,
    likes: body.likes || 0,
    user: user._id,
  });

  const savedBlog = await blog.save();
  user.blogs = user.blogs.concat(savedBlog.id);
  await user.save();

  response.status(201).json(savedBlog);
});

blogsRouter.put('/:id', async (request, response, next) => { });
blogsRouter.delete('/:id', middleware.userExtractor, async (request, response) => { });

module.exports = blogsRouter;


Shouldn't the user.name be First Last, not Matti Luukkainen? If the remove button isn't showing up, then blog.user.username === loggedInUsername is false, so it seems you're logged in as a different user (presumably Matti?) than your mock blog post user name.

yes you are right, I corrected the name. The error still occurs. Also, updated the Playwright GUI output with the First and Last name.

Did you try logging those usernames to see what their values are and why that comparison is failing, assuming you expect it not to? In React, right before rendering: console.log(blog.user.username, loggedInUsername, blog.user.name). If that's not where the discrepancy occurs, then add more logs to the front and backend and look at the network requests until you figure out exactly where the discrepancy first appears. That's probably where the issue is. Is the issue that mongoose doesn't populate the user when you use PW, but it does when you do it manually?

I have added these console logs and updated the image above. The values are undefined in the Playwright testing GUI, but they appear on the frontend. What is PW?

PW = Playwright. If they're undefined, then trace back to the discrepancy. It sounds like the "user": {...} is being turned into "user": "id string" incorrectly somewhere, so I guess you have a mongo discrepancy, or something to do with local storage that isn't set up the same way between the two environments. Better clear out local storage on both envs and figure out where the discrepancy starts.

I think I know the issue, but don't know how to solve it. When I add a new blog, the
object is { title: first blog title,  author: first blog author,  url: first blog url, likes: 0, user: 665fac3a37d34c2da6c8f899 }. Update doesn't happen quickly. I think I need to fix the useEffect in App.jsx with the getAll service to ensure that the page takes new values upon every new addition. I tried to add blogs as a dependency to the useEffect but with that my backend runs infinitely. If I add initialBlogs as a dependency it gives React Hook useEffect has an unnecessary dependency.

I figured out the answer. I fixed my POST request in the blogs.js backend controller.
blogsRouter.post('/', middleware.userExtractor, async (request, response) => {
  const user = request.user;
  const body = request.body;

  const blog = new Blog({
    title: body.title,
    author: body.author,
    url: body.url,
    likes: body.likes || 0,
    user: user._id,
  });

  const savedBlog = await blog.save();
  user.blogs = user.blogs.concat(savedBlog._id);
  await user.save();

  // convert the user id string field to user object with: 
  // user: {id: "", username: "", name: "W"}
  const blogReturned = await savedBlog.populate('user', { username: 1, name: 1 });

  response.status(201).json(blogReturned);
});

After I save the object in the original object shape. I change the shape when returning the values to the UI by adding the username and name fields when populating the object. I did it like this because I don't want to change the shape of how I am storing values in the database.
I don't know if this is an efficient way of achieving this.
Now my Playwright tests pass without any issues. Please see image below:

